# How do I explicitly specify a Model's table-name mapping in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model class called Countries and I want it to map to a DB table called 'cc'.

How is that done in Rails?

Answer (score 492, accepted):

#### Rails >= 3.2 (including Rails 4+, 5+, 6+ and 7+):

```
class Countries < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "cc"
end
```

#### Rails <= 3.1:

```
class Countries < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.set_table_name "cc"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Is it the best practice to specify `table_name` for every model?

Comment: @MikeC - No. It's the rails way to be as brief as possible and only write code when it overwrites conventions.

Comment: @SungWonCho Its not best practice to specify table name on each model, only just use this when you need a different name for table

Comment: Note that this assignment ignores the `table_name_prefix`. If you have one set, use `self.table_name = "#{table_name_prefix}cc"`

Answer (score 145):

```
class Countries < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "cc"
end
```

In Rails 3.x this is the way to specify the table name.