# Ruby on Rails working with pre-existing database. Rails makes everything plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

What is the deal with this?  I'm working with a pre-existing that I did not do myself.  Everything in the database is labeled in singular form.  user, security, spec, etc.  I guess the right way would be users, securities, specs.  At least that's what ruby on rails try's to lookup when I generate a scaffold .

How do I specifically state to use user instead of users in the sql.  I don't see anywhere in my project where it is looking up the sql.  I mean if my model is user you would think it would try to lookup user.  Instead of users.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can override the naming convention used if you wish.  There is a pluralisation engine which works very well integrated into Rails, but as I say, when creating them I was certain you could stop it from automatically creating a name.  What's the problem with the default naming convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `set_table_name :name_of_the_table` in your model ([source](http://www.arthurneil.com/ruby-on-rails/singlecustom-table-name-for-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)).

So:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :user
end
```

The reason they use plural for the table and singular for the model is because an instance of the model represents one user, whereas the table contains all the users. It's just to make it more readable and logical.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifiy the table name:

[How do I explicitly specify a Model's table-name mapping in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails)