# How to set database table name in Rails 4 with dot in name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have table with dot in name and cannot make query to it. My table name is: site.com_news

In model, according to [How do I explicitly specify a Model's table-name mapping in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails) i set:

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "site.com_news"
end
```

In log:

```
E, [2014-10-06T17:22:34.119037 #15975] ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: Table 'site.com_news' doesn't exist: SELECT `site`.`com_news`.* FROM `site`.`com_news`
I, [2014-10-06T17:22:34.150211 #15975]  INFO -- :   Rendered news/index.html.erb within layouts/application (36.2ms)
I, [2014-10-06T17:22:34.150696 #15975]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65ms
F, [2014-10-06T17:22:34.155848 #15975] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Table 'site.com_news' doesn't exist: SELECT `site`.`com_news`.* FROM `site`.`com_news`):
```

How to escape dot character in table name? I try "`site.com_news`" - does not work.

According http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html:
**Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.**

Thank you
But in PHP this construction is work :(

Comment: Are you sure your database name isn't `site` and your table name isn't `com_news`?

Comment: your title contradicts your question text: "How to set *database* name in Rails 4 with dot in name" vs "I have *table* with dot in name": so is it a table or database name which contains the dot?

Comment: It is mysql error. Table name should not contain '.'(dot). Check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: My mistake. Database name is site-portal. Table name is site.com_news. Query, for example, is: SELECT * from `site-portal`.`site.com_news`

I changed title from "database" to "database table"

Comment: I guess, mysql won't allow such naming convention for table creation. Please recheck the table name. If possible share the dump for that table.

Comment: [code]
mysql> show tables from `site-portal`;
+-------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_site-portal               |
+-------------------------------------+
| site.com_news                       |
| site.com_reply                      |
| site.com_vacancy                    |
| site.com_vote                       |
| site1.com_news                      |
| site1.com_reply                     |
| site1.com_vacancy                   |
| site1.com_vote                      |
...
+-------------------------------------+
109 rows in set (0.00 sec)
[/code]

Comment: mysql> show tables from `site-portal`;
    +-------------------------------------+
    | Tables_in_site-portal               |
    +-------------------------------------+
    | site.com_news                       |
    | site.com_reply                      |
    | site.com_vacancy                    |
    | site.com_vote                       |
    | site1.com_news                      |
    | site1.com_reply                     |
    | site1.com_vacancy                   |
    | site1.com_vote             
    ...
    +-------------------------------------+
    109 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: mysql> select * from `site-portal`.`site1.com_vote`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 29
 Parent: 0
Caption: Какие условия Вы считаете наиболее важными при выборе конюши для своей лошади?
   IsOn: 1
    Pid: 1
   Vote: 445
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
 Parent: 1
Caption: <b>Да</b>. Однозначно!
   IsOn: 1
    Pid: 0
   Vote: 3
....

mysql allow this way (with dot in table name)