# Rails 4: rename model corresponding to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Situation: I had Rails model and table in database which were working. I had to rename table name (it was not small change, almost whole name changed) and now I need to change model's name so it corresponds to table's new name. What is the best way to accomplish my goal?

From things I've found: `rails destroy model model_name` and then generate new model - but I'm not sure if it'll work the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to change the model's name if you don't want to. As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails), you can simply add a line to your model that explicitly sets its table name. For example, if you changed the table name from `apples` to `oranges`:

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.set_table_name("oranges")
  ...
end
```

That will allow you to keep all of the references to the model throughout your application working. If you truly *have* to change the class name as well, you will have to update all your references to that model throughout your code.

Comment: Updating refernces is one thing, but how should I deal with the old model?

Comment: If you really want to go that route and update all the references, you just manually change the name of the model at the top of the file (and rename the file to the new name). You will need to change the name of the controller, the routes, and tests accordingly.