# How do I access a model's table name in my rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a engine which validates an Excel file and then saves it to a database. But my engine is not providing any migration. Table to save data will be provided by the app.

Now my problem is, **how do I access the table name in my engine's model where data needs to be saved?**

For example, I have a model `upload.rb` and app provides table `admins` where I want to save data.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails) and setting `self.table_name = 'admins'` worked but it's not possible to set table name everytime.

I am very new to rails and I'm building an engine for the first time.

Here is code for my engine's model

```
module MyEngine
  class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'admins'

    def validate(file)
      spreadsheet = open_excel(file)
      header = spreadsheet.row(1)
      2.upto(spreadsheet.last_row) do
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        upload = Upload.new(row)
        upload.save!
      end
    end

    private

    def open_excel(file)
      case File.extname(file)
      when ".xls", ".xlsx" then Roo::Spreadsheet.open file
      else raise "File format not supported"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here during development i can set `self.table_name = 'admins'` but in production its hard to change table name every time.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to access the database directly, is that it? Why wouldn't you just instantiate a new instance of Admin and then save it? The table name shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: It will only work if my model name is `admin`. But model name could be anything. Anyways, as of now requirements are changed by the client, So its not needed now bt thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one below:

```
 self.class.table_name
```

Comment: the problem is that `table_name` is not known. `admins` was for example. It could be `users`, `employees`, so is there a way to set table name in rails engine.

Comment: If you are trying to get table name directly from the model name then try User.table_name

Comment: But how will my engine know that model name is `User` in app, it could be `Admin` or anything.

Comment: Share some code that you have written for the engine.

Comment: Added the code. Here its hard to set `self.table_name` everytime.

Comment: One question: Couldn't you get the name from the spreadsheet some way? Like the excel filename being the same name you want for the table? Or the name of the entity represented in that spreadsheet being part of the data in the spreadsheet, like in a certain row/col position you could read? Then you could have a `set_table_name` method in your model, being called after you grad this information but before storing the spreadsheet's data to a certain table?

Comment: No i can't because different users can have different file name, diff columns, order of columns can be different. And we can't put a constraint for filename. Anyways thanks for suggestion.