# How to define a has_many :through relation when table and class names are different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to know if it is possible to define a `has_many :through` relation when table and class names for the models are different from each other; an example showing the standard doctor, appointment, patient example would suffice.

For the sake of example, let's say the tables are:

```
res_doctor
res_appointment
res_patient
```

and the models are:

```
ModelDoctor
ModelAppointment
ModelPatient
```

I want to know if such a thing is possible or not.

If it is possible, I would be glad if someone can modify this example to fit the scenario I have described:

```
class ResDoctor < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'res_doctor'

  # Add code here
end

class ResAppointment < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'res_appointment'

  # Add code here
end

class ResPatient < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'res_patient'

  # Add code here
end
```

Thanks!

PS: This is not a duplicate of [mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4613574/4998569). Do not mark questions as duplicates without understanding them please.

Comment: In the model you should have written something like this: `self.table_name = "res_doctor"`, that should do the job I guess. And wherever required you can mention the `foreign_key`.

Answer (score 1):

This way should work, [Duplicate Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails)

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "custom_name"


  has_many :appointments   
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments 
end
```