# Do I have to perform migrations in rails or can I just create ORM classes and define the relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The question pretty much says it all.

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I'm trying to figure out active record. According to a few pieces that I've read, Rails will interrogate the database (in my case PostgreSQL 9.6) and pick up the columns from that. The way I read this, does that mean I can create the database in PostgreSQL, create ORM classes and define the relationships in the ORM classes?

My background is in databases and it's been a while since I've done any web development and prior to 1/8/2018 I had never even touched Ruby let alone Rails. So, the ultimate question is: Can I create the database in PostgreSQL without Rails migrations and then create the ORM classes with the relationships between the classes (tables) defined in them?

Comment: You should probably set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` (`:ruby `is the default) see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! You'd just need to connect to the existing db in `config/database.yml` and generate a `schema` file by running `rake db:schema:dump`. Remember to go by [Rails naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) for ORM Classes (called `Models` in RoR). You can also explicitly set table names for every model by adding `self.table_name = "posts"` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4613574/3284936) answer)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was hoping.