# Connection between oracle table and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle11g

So, i'm having a question, how to create connection between oracle table `NOTES` and Ruby web-application? Basically he should save data in and read from that table. Don't wanna use `plsql.

Using:
**Ruby:** 1.8.7
**Rails:** 2.3.4

P.S Might be stupid question, but can't understand how to make it. New in ruby :).

Comment: (1) You need to have an adapter that will connect your Rails model (Note model, i assume) and 'notes' table in your oracle db. See this gem that has the adapter. https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced (2) you need to update your config/database.yml to connect to your oracle database (3) if you set your adapter and config/database.yml correctly, you can try to do "Note.all" in your rails console.

Comment: Forgot to write. Gem is already installed and yml is configured. There is a lot of other tables that is connected and working, the thing is idk how to connect the new one. I have file in `models` and also in `controllers` folder, created table. And nothing, he can't see any column.

Comment: If you are connecting to "notes" table, i think your model (note.rb) should be of class "Note". Otherwise you have to explicitly say in the model file which table to connect to. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails)

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro http://prntscr.com/kokn18 It was done like this. And how to check if there is connection between them?

Comment: try: (1) you need to properly indent your code (add 2 spaces indentation to all code inside your class. (2) add "end" at the end of the file/class definition

Comment: To check connection i usually just use the rails console, and access using the model, which is: "Note.all" or "Note.create(...)"

Comment: And if i don't have access to rails console? Cos of the error(can't be fixed).

Comment: Are you running in development environment? If you should be able to see the rails logs right? You can try to query in controller, for example the index action for notes controller. Query for Note.all, then check the rails logs, it should display the requests there. You should see something like SELECT * from notes...

Comment: For me i use this gem (https://github.com/pry/pry) or the default one i think is byebug, this will allow you to pause the code by inserting the commands in your code and using the terminal. The terminal then can act as a rails console where you can do stuff similarly.

Comment: _And if i don't have access to rails console? Cos of the error(can't be fixed)._ In your `note` model, you're missing keyword `end` like @JeffreyMCastro has mentioned. Also, once you have that in place, open `rails console` and try to create a `new` note. If you're not sure how to do that, then in `rails console`, run `Note.column_names` and share the output.